# Cannot generate instances of abstract factory UserFactory ( Factory boy)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, pytest, factory-boy

factory.errors.FactoryError: Cannot generate instances of abstract factory UserFactory; Ensure UserFactory.Meta.model is set and UserFactory.Meta.abstract is either not set or False.
**Im using factory boy library To test my functions**

my class UserFactory Here
[UserFactory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMHqt.png)

```
import factory
import factory.django
from users.models import Users
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.db import models   

     class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
        
            username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: f"user_{n:004}")
            email = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda user: f"{user.username}@example")
            password = factory.LazyFunction(make_password("password"))
        
            class Meta:
                model: Users
            abstract = True
```

Here Model User I'm inheritance from class abstract user
[User Class Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPKav.png)

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Users(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
```

I added class meta abstract and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all: factory_boy will only allow you to instantiate from a factory if said factory has a `Meta.model` and is not marked `Meta.abstract = True`.

Typically, one would use:

```py
class MyFactory(...):
  class Meta:
    model = SomeModel
```

In advanced cases, some projects might have abstract factories; in which case that abstractness must be disabled:

```py
class SomeAbstractFactory(...):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    abstract = True

class MyFactory(SomeAbstractFactory):
  class Meta:
    abstract = False
```

In your code example, you have written `model: User` instead of `model = User`; it can easily be fixed with:

```py
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    # (No "abstract = " clause)
```